# Nagios - Host/Service dependancy

Tags: nagios

I am implementing Nagios for a customer.

The customer has the following request;

We have a PC (PC-1) and a server (Server-1). The PC only has ping monitoring in Nagios, the server has Ping monitoring but also a service check (check if Citrix is up).

We would like PC-1 to go to a warning state when the Citrix service on Server-1 is in a down state. The reason we want that is for reporting purposes.

I am aware of service to service dependancy, but I am wondering if this service to host dependancy would work and how :).

Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. See the [docs on dependencies](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/dependencies.html).

You don't explicitly make a service dependent on another host. Rather, you must make it dependent on a service **on** that host. Since services are also implicitly dependent on their hosts, this results in the behavior you want.

You can use your ping service check for this purpose, which is the only time you'd actually need a check_ping (or check_icmp) service check.

If you read the section on actual **host** dependencies, you'll see that the parent/child relationship is suggested, instead.